# Qt OpenGL framebuffer to image

Tags: qt, opengl, framebuffer

I'm drawing the framebuffer to an image, it used to work fine, however something broke and I have no idea what..

Any help would be great.

I get the error "QGLFramebufferObject: Framebuffer incomplete, missing attachment."

It seems to work intermittently.

```
VoxelEditor::VoxelEditor(QWidget *parent)
    : QGLWidget(QGLFormat(QGL::SampleBuffers), parent)
{

    makeCurrent();
    catchFbo = new QGLFramebufferObject(PICTURE_SIZE, PICTURE_SIZE);




void VoxelEditor::renderToImage() {
    saveGLState();
    const int nrPics = 360 / DEGREES_BETWEEN_PICTURES;
    for (int i = 0; i < nrPics; i++) {
        catchFbo->bind();
        glColorMask(true, true, true, true);
        glClearColor(0,0,0,0);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);
        glEnable(GL_MULTISAMPLE);
        glLoadIdentity();

        GLfloat x = GLfloat(PICTURE_SIZE) / PICTURE_SIZE;
        glFrustum(-x, +x, -1.0, +1.0, 1.0, 1000.0);
        glViewport(0, 0, PICTURE_SIZE, PICTURE_SIZE);

        drawScreenshot(i);
        catchFbo->release();

        QImage catchImage = catchFbo->toImage();
        catchImage.save("object/test" + QString::number(i) + ".png");
    }
    glDisable(GL_MULTISAMPLE);

    restoreGLState();
}
```

Comment: show us the code that initializes your framebuffer.

Comment: oh yeah, missed that. I scanned over the source looking for `glGenFramebuffers`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this by putting the creation of the fbo in the rendertoimage call.

It seemed at creation it was valid and had the appropriate attachment, but at execution it failed..

Perhaps creating the fbo in the initializeGL call would work as well.

Comment: I had the same problem but I was creating the FBO in `initializeGL()`, after moving it to the `paintGL()` (making sure it only executes once of course) it worked. So it seems `initializeGL` is not the place either.

Answer (score 0):

Have you check you buffer with isValid() method? Try to release buffer after call toImage() method.

Comment: I tried to relase the buffer after toImage, but that doesn't matter.

Comment: How can I forget it?! creating fbo in initializeGL is right way, I had simmilar problem some time ago.